# Overwriting one Json config on another in Java

Tags: java, json, overwrite

I have base config file x.json which is something like

```
{
  "key-i"  : "value-i",
  "key-ii" : {
    "key-ii-a" : "value-ii-a",
    "key-ii-b" : {
      "key-ii-b-1" : "value-ii-b-1",
      "key-ii-b-2" : "value-ii-b-2"
    }
  }
}
```

and another env specific config file x_env.json which is something like

```
{
  "key-ii" : {
    "key-ii-b" : {
      "key-ii-b-2" : "different-value-ii-b-2"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to overwrite only config present in x_env.json on top of x.json which should look like

```
{
  "key-i"  : "value-i",
  "key-ii" : {
    "key-ii-a" : "value-ii-a",
    "key-ii-b" : {
      "key-ii-b-1" : "value-ii-b-1",
      "key-ii-b-2" : "different-value-ii-b-2"
    }
  }
}
```

This is only an example and x.json can be any json and how can I generically overwrite x_env.json on x.json for any json structure in Java.

I am using the gson library and following to parse

```
JsonParser.parseString(IOUtils.toString(ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("x.json"))).getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the current code you have for reading/writing json configuration including information about any libraries that you are using for parsing json

Comment: Edited the question to add the above info

Comment: Have a look at [`json patching`](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch)